# Unable to implement screenshots using implicit intent

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to take a screenshot of my app and then view it in another application using implicit intent. When I hit the button the view of the screenshot is not displaying and I do not know where the screenshot is being stored on the emulator.

Do I need to create a directory before trying to store the screenshot? I think my mkdirs() is incorrect.

```
package com.levirs.example.screenshooter;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                screenshoot();
            }
        });
    }

    private void screenshoot() {
        Date date = new Date();
        CharSequence now = android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", date);
        String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ScreenShooter/" + now + ".jpg";

        View root = getWindow().getDecorView();
        root.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(root.getDrawingCache());
        root.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        File file = new File(filename);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutputStream);
            fileOutputStream.flush();
            fileOutputStream.close();

            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.levirs.example.screenshooter">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: `I think my mkdirs() is incorrect.` Well you are not checking the return value. So you dont know when in it fails. Further you should only call mkdirs if the directory does not exist yet.

Comment: `Uri.fromFile(file)` has been banned, in effect, for five years. Your app should be crashing with a `FileUriExposedException`. Please stop using `Uri.fromFile()` and switch to `FileProvider` and `getUriForFile()`. Also, please use a concrete MIME type, not a wildcard.

Comment: @CommonsWare the error I receive is W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/ScreenShooter/2021-02-21_09:51:41.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: Bear in mind that you need to request `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` at runtime in addition to in the manifest. And, bear in mind that you will not have write access to your desired location on Android 11+, once your `targetSdkVersion` reaches 30. I recommend storing your screenshot somewhere else that does not need permissions, such as `getCacheDir()` or `getExternalCacheDir()` on `Context`. And, you will need to set up `FileProvider`.

Comment: @CommonsWare so if I store it in the cachedir instead I will not need to have the write request in the manifest or runtime?

Comment: "I will not need to have the write request in the manifest or runtime?" -- yes. `getCacheDir()` is available without permissions on all versions of Android. `getExternalCacheDir()` is available without permissions on Android 4.4 and higher.